# Error 34 on trend_weekly for Tweepy

Tags: python, tweepy, trend

I am working on a project using Tweepy for Python 2.7. Actually, I would like to collect a list of several trends on Twitter say from 2014-05-01 to 2014-06-01.

To do so, I wanted to use trend_weekly given by the Twitter API. Unfortunately enough, this function is deprecated (limited to API 1) and there no exists any updated version. Then I tried this :

```
api = tweepy.API(auth)

trends_weekly = bind_api(
        search_api = True,
        path = '/1/trends/weekly.json',
        payload_type = 'json',
        allowed_param = ['date', 'exclude']
    )

trends = api.trends_weekly()
```

But, I have this error:

> TweepError: [{u'message': u'Sorry, that page does not exist', u'code':
>   34}]

Concurrently, when I call trend_place or trend_available, which have been updated for the API 1.1, I have no error. However, I can't do what I want with these ones.

I am a newbie in Python and Tweepy, this is why I am looking for your help. Please forgive me if this question has already been asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can no longer use the `trends/weekly` because it is only included in the API v1 and Twitter now only supports v1.1 (the older version is no longer active).

The [actual response of a query](https://api.twitter.com/1/trends/weekly.json) of the v1 API tells you this:

> {"errors":[{"message":"The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.","code":64}]}

The [relevant documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/trends/weekly) gives you the same message:

> **Deprecation notice!** Version 1 of the API is now deprecated. This document may describe an outdated version of the API. Please move to Version 1.1 of the API as soon as possible.

Unfortunately, there is now no way to get these weekly trends (other than actually constructing a list yourself, over time). Twitter just doesn't support it anymore. A site like [Topsy](http://topsy.com/) might be helpful for historical tweet data; I've never used it myself but have seen frequent recommendations for it.

Comment: Thank you. I need to think about another way then.